# Genexus Smart Device - Crear archivo texto

Tags: android, archivo, genexus

requiero crear un archivo de texto desde un aplicativo Genexus Android.
Las dudas que tengo:

- Como direcciono donde se creara el archivo.
- Si esta fuera de las carpetas de la aplicación por ejemplo /Storage/SdCard, como darle permisos para que pueda crearlo
  Genexus 17 U9
  Android
  C#
  Offline

Agradecido con los comentarios

Comment: Como estas?
Tenes 2 formas, 1 es guardarlo en la memoria que el SO reserva para la app o en un external storage (sd card por ej). La primera vas a poder guardar, pero no es accesible por el usuario desde el file system del device, solo la puede acceder la app para usarla. La otra forma, te recomiendo que veas este documento (particularmente la parte de 'ExternalFilesPath'): https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?27388,Directory+Data+Type+Static+properties

Comment: Hola, recuerda crear tu pregunta en base a [ask], es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, saludos.

Comment: Estimado, segun lo enviado

&file.Source = Directory.ApplicationDataPath + &file.Separator + "someFile.txt"

Puedo reemplazar el Directory.ApplicationDataPath por ejemplo por SDcart
o tengo que hacer algo adicional para que me permita escribir fuera de carpeta de la aplicacion

gracias

Comment: Con Directory.ExternalFilePath, escribes dentro de la "sdcard", pero en el directorio de la aplicacion.
Donde quieres copiar el archivo y para que? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Usaría el [tipo de datos Directory](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?27388,Directory%20Data%20Type%20Static%20properties) para armar la ruta al archivo.

Ej:

```
&file.Source = Directory.ApplicationDataPath + &file.Separator + "someFile.txt"
```

Escribir fuera de las carpetas de la aplicación, en las últimas versiones de Android requiere [permisos especiales o está prohibido](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#permissions).

Saludos,